# Delete or disable user in mediawiki

Tags: mediawiki

How can i disable or delete an user in mediawiki?
I can delete the records from the db but i am not sure if this would affect anything else in the wiki.
Any suggestions would be welcome

Thanks
Prady

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's a special page that Admin users can see, `/Special:BlockIP`.  Block them there.

You can also get to it from the Special Pages page, `/Special:SpecialPages`.

Comment: I think this feature only blocks the write access. What if you want to completely block them from reading (I have a private/login-required wiki)

Answer (score 16):

#### 1. This solutions is available out of the box for MediaWiki 1.16+

The user and all the contributed content will remain but they will not be able to log in any more.

There are two steps that need to be done:

- First [block the user](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Blocking_users) using the link in Special Pages.

  - Blocking can be performed against user id or IP address to prevent them from **editing** the wiki.
  - They will still be able to log in and view content.
- Then in `LocalSettings.php` add `$wgBlockDisablesLogin=true;` ([$wgBlockDisablesLogin](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgBlockDisablesLogin)).

  - Now upon logging in the user will be greeted with `Login error. This user is blocked. Login not allowed.`.

#### 2. This solutions requires an extension that works with MediaWiki 1.29+

> If you want to completely remove access to a user, e.g. on a simple private wiki, it's not possible to simply delete the account (unless no edits have been made); you can block it, but the user will still be able to read pages. However, using [User Merge and Delete](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:UserMerge) extension you can merge the account in another one and delete the former; the original account will then "disappear".

Also:

> If you want to preserve history readability (i.e., to have edits from the user to be still shown under his name), you can create a new account e.g. with username "OriginalUserName (deactivated)" and then merge "OriginalUserName" into the former, or even use Renameuser extension.

I suppose if you wanted to revive the user later on you would need to repeat this process but this time you would merge `OriginalUserName (deactivated)` into `OriginalUserName`.

See [Preventing Access](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Preventing_access#Removing_accounts) page in the MediaWiki manual.

Comment: `$wgBlockDisablesLogin=true;` works great. Anyone with a private access wiki should follow this answer.

Answer (score 0):

you could also reset the password of the user via

- `/Special:PasswordReset`

*note: I would not recommend deleting data via scripts in the DB. there are various functionalities for rolling back unwanted user edits, merging contribution from one user to another, etc.*